# Grabbing the existing address data to use with Smart Map

Tags: plugin-smartmap

I'm new to Craft CMS, so pardon me. I've been using the [VZ Address](https://github.com/elivz/VzAddress-Craft) plugin to handle all our address entries, and have a couple hundred of workshop address entries already.

I'm trying to use [Smart Map](https://plugins.doublesecretagency.com/smart-map/) to generate a map, search by zip code, for the workshop addresses that are already been created with VZ Address. How can I grab that info from VZ Address field and use it with Smart Map?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend migrating all of your map data into a Smart Map Address field. Once you've got everything contained within Smart Map, it will be much easier to render maps and conduct proximity searches.

The best way to migrate would be to use something like [Feed Me](https://github.com/verbb/feed-me)...

1. Create a simple JSON or RSS feed which contains only (A) the entry ID, and (B) the VZ Address data.
2. Pull that feed right back into the same site, putting the address data into your Smart Map field.

Once you’ve migrated to Smart Map, it opens up a lot more possibilities for using that data!

Comment: Thank you, Lindsey! Appreciate your help.